# convexity of two convex function combined

Tags: optimization, convex

If I have such an optimization problem:
$$
\arg\min_{x,z} \dfrac{||y-x||_2^2}{z}+z(||y-x||_2^2)
$$
where $y$ is known and $z>0$.

If $z$ is fixed, then this function w.r.t $x$ is convex. Similarly, if $x$ is given, this function w.r.t $z$ is also convex. However, I wonder:

1. Is the original function w.r.t $x$ and $z$ jointly convex?
2. If so, can I optimize the function alternatively by fixing $x$ solving for $z$ and fixing $z$ solving for $x$ until converging?
3. Are there any relevant papers/materials that I should read for this kind of question?

Comment: I hesitate to give an answer because I'm not sure I'm correct. But WLOG suppose y=0. Then we have $\| x\|_2^2 ( \frac{1}{z} + z)$. This is not convex unless we restrict the domain of z to be positive. In fact, if x is given we have $c(z + \frac{1}{z}$ where c is a constant. In addition to being undefined at 0, it is non-convex, contrary to what you said in your post.

Comment: In general, a book on functional analysis ought to answer these types of questions -- Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications* is quite good.

Comment: Look at Boyds Convex Analysis

Comment: Any bilinear function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, such as $f(x,y)=xy$, provides simple counterexamples to $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen is referring to the freely available "Convex Optimization", by Boyd and Vandenberghe https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ . Section 3.2 is "Operations that preserve convexity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not jointly convex in x and z, even when z > 0.

Consider the example x and z both being 1-D. Let y=0, x=1, z=2. Then the Hessian w.r.t x and z has eigenvalues 5.43 and -0.18, and is therefore indefinite.

I suggest you try using a general purpose nonlinear non-convex optimizer in which you can impose the non-negativity constraint on z. Either use a local optimizer, or you could try using a global optimizer, such as BARON, if the problem dimension is not too high. If using BARON, you will need to place finite lower and upper bounds on all variables - if they are achieved at the optimum, then you need to adjust.

I would suggest trying off the shelf optimizers before trying to gin up your own algorithm. You can try an alternating optimization as you proposed in 2, but I don't think there is any guarantee it will converge, and if it does converge, that it will do so to the correct answer.